# Android MVP Adapter

Tags: java, android, comparative-review, mvp

While implementing Android `Activity` component using **MVP pattern** a discussion arose - who should be responsible of creating list adapter - view or presenter?
If presenter creates adapter, apparently `View` needs to provide `Context` for `Presenter` to be able to instantiate adapter:

```
public interface MyView {

void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter);

Context getContext();
}
```

And then `presenter` could easily set adapter:

```
view.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(view.getContext(), ...));
```

The second approach would be allowing View to create Adapter object and thus expose data to it, for example:

```
public interface MyView {

void setAdapter(MyData[] data);

}
```

In first example I am exposing `Context` object that I would like to avoid, but in the second example I am letting `View` to decide on `adapter` implementation and expose data to it as well. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would keep the presenter free from Android code, so you can unit test it. You can pass the data from your presenter to the view and instantiate the adapter there.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyView {

     public void setMyAdapter(List<String> items) {
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
}
```

and call this method from the presenter via the MyView interface.

Comment: So the second approach. What limits me from unit-testing it in the first approach?

Comment: What are you going to do about requiring a context in the presenter in the first approach?

Comment: I will provide mock view with MockContext

Comment: I would leave any context or android specifics out of your business logic. Makes it much easier to port the code to another project that is non-android and cleanly separates content from the wrappers and views.

Answer (score 1):

I would also go with the seconds approach. A main goal of having MVP is to separate views from logic and a presenter having a knowledge about particular list implementation is violating Open/Close principle. So if you change your `ListView` into `RecyclerView`, you have to refactor presenter too.